# Google Dataprep Import/Export flows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

Does the Import/Export Flow option only work for the same project the original flow comes from? Having exported a flow from the flows page, I can't seem to import it into another account

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To [import](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Import-Flow_118228662#import) a for you need to click on the 3 dot next to the "create a flow" button and chose the zip file that was created when you exported a flow.

When you say you can't seem to import into and other account, can you be more specific? do you get a error message? If so you may encounter a bug which should be handled in The [Trifacta Support Portal](https://community.trifacta.com/s/support-portal).